# Custom Struct-returning function stuck on input?

Tags: c, struct, scanf, modulo, rational-numbers

I wanted to make a function with structs to simplify rational numbers ,
 one member is the numerator(int) and the other is the denominator(int) but the program stucks at input!!
I am aware that scanf() is a bit risky but I thought its just a couple of integers!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct rational{
    int num;
    int den;
}rational;

rational makerational(int num,int den);
void printrational(rational r);
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("\n\n Input integers for fraction:");
    scanf(" %d%d",&a,&b);
    printrational(makerational(a,b));
}
rational makerational(int a,int b){
    int live=1; 
    rational r;
    r.num=a;
    r.den=b;
  while(live){  
    if(!(r.num%2 && r.den%2)){
        r.num/=2;
        r.den/=2;
    }else if(!(r.num%3 && r.den%3)){
        r.num/=3;
        r.den/=3;
    }else if(!(r.num%5 && r.den%5)){
        r.num/=5;
        r.den/=5;
    }else if(!(r.num%7 && r.den%7)){
        r.num/=7;
        r.den/=7;
    }else live--;
  }
    return r;
}
void printrational(rational r){
    printf("\nFRACTION -> %d/%d\n",r.num,r.den);
}
```

Comment: What input are you supplying? Program will run if you supply, for instance, `2 3`. I think for your input you are entering an infinite loop. Do some debugging! print the values of r.num and r.den each time round the loop/

Comment: If I use 7 10 or 8 20

Comment: Please, stop using TABs to indent (and use only spaces); it results in a mess, here and elsewhere.

Comment: Why inf loop ? if the modulo is not 0 , !(1&&1)=0 right?

Comment: @meaning-matters ok should I press space 2-4 times each nested command to indent? (its a bit impractical)

Comment: It's an infinite loop. Do you know any debugging techniques at all?

Comment: Use an editor that has an option to generate 4 spaces when hitting the TAB key.  I don't know code editors that don't support this.  Then, getting crappy formatted code is much more impractical.

Comment: The fun fact that my editor (gedit) edits how much spaces Tab generates (I have probably messed the copy-code-paste)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You getting stuck in an infinite loop here:

```
while(live){  
    if(!(r.num%2 && r.den%2)){
        r.num/=2;
        r.den/=2;
    }

    …
}
```

For example, when `r.num == 1` and `r.den == 2`, consider what's happening:

**Iteration 1**

```
r.num % 2 == 1 % 2 == 1
r.den % 2 == 2 % 2 == 0
!(1 && 0) == 1

r.num / 2 == 1 / 2 == 0
r.den / 2 == 2 / 2 == 1
```

**Iteration 2**

```
r.num % 2 == 0 % 2 == 0
r.den % 2 == 1 % 2 == 1
!(0 && 1) == 1

r.num / 2 == 0 / 2 == 0
r.den / 2 == 1 / 2 == 0
```

**Iteration 3 to infinity and beyond…**

```
r.num % 2 == 0 % 2 == 0
r.den % 2 == 0 % 2 == 0
!(0 && 0) == 1

r.num / 2 == 0 / 2 == 0
r.den / 2 == 0 / 2 == 0
```

Change the expressions in the branching statements to something like this to correct your logic:

```
while(live)
{
    if((r.num % 2 == 0) && (r.den % 2 == 0))
    {
        r.num /= 2;
        r.den /= 2;
    }

    …
}
```

Comment: because when the remainder is not 0 , its not necessary 1 (or handled like that) right?

Comment: Its certainly more clear now;
one condition to check if 'r.num/den!=0' should suffice ....?

Comment: If I don't use ! entirely for example the program would output 0/0 for input such as 1/2 right?

Comment: @niCk If you took away the `!` and the input was `4/2`, for example, your final answer would be, `2/1`, which is what you want, right?

Comment: with || for example one div with remainder 0 the other not 0 (5 mod assume its handled like logical 1) then 0||1=1 (1 without both numbers  evenly divided by 2)

Comment: @niCk See my new comment.  Ignore the one about `||`.

Comment: 4 2 input (without !) returned 1/0 and I saw the edit

Comment: Both mod's should be zero so this (!a)&&(!b) or !(a^^b) (^^ XOR if not mistaken) is valid, correct?

Comment: @niCk Yes.  Or you can do something like this: `if((r.num%2 == 0) && (r.den%2 == 0))`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, when you enter 8 20,  numbers change like fallowing;

4 10

2 5

1 2

0 1

0 0 <--- here is the infinite loop

reason is, integer rounds down the number, you should add a control statement for the case that numbers reach 0

Comment: I think I messed up the logical expression the point of this:4/8->1/2

Comment: Confused a bit, The supposed way of operating was , If both members are divided then do simplification else check other ... else live=0 exit.

Comment: you are not checking for both members. Your if statements are only checking for 1 number for example, you have 2 5;

if(!(r.num%2 && r.den%2)) // this line is becomes this;

if(!(0 && 1))

if(!0)

if(1)

you should use it without !